# Getting Paginated Outputs from DynamoDB Table Using Scan Operation

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-dynamodb

I am doing a scan operation on my DynamoDB table. Code is below.

I am able to get results of the first page, where limit is defined by "scanExpression.limit", but how do I get successive pages?

```
    AWSDynamoDBScanExpression *scanExpression = [AWSDynamoDBScanExpression new];
    scanExpression.limit = @10;

    [[dynamoDBObjectMapper scan:[Post class]
                     expression:scanExpression]
     continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
         if (task.error) {
             NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error);
         }
         if (task.exception) {
             NSLog(@"The request failed. Exception: [%@]", task.exception);
         }
         if (task.result) {
             AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;
             for (Post *post in paginatedOutput.items) {

                 if (arraycount == 0){
                     [_FeedImageURL addObject:post.ImageURL];}
                 }
                 else{
                     [_FeedImageURL insertObject:post.ImageURL atIndex:arraycount];
                 }

                 arraycount=arraycount +1;

             }
         }

         return nil;
     }];
```

Comment: I think you pass the key you found in NextEvaluatedKey in your first batch to "ExclusiveStartKey" to get next set of records

Comment: How will that look like and how do I call NextEvaluatedKey and ExclusiveStartKey? I am using Mobile SDK version 2.

Comment: When you will call 1st scan you will receive NextEvaluatedKey, pass that key's value to ExclusiveStartKey in next scan ..continue till you dont get NextEvaKey..

Comment: When I do the following: self.lastEvaluatedKey = paginatedOutput.lastEvaluatedKey; scanExpression.exclusiveStartKey = self.lastEvaluatedKey; I notice I get the correct lastEvaluatedKey but the exclusiveStartKey is not updated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you update the code in your questions the would be effective